# Laravel: Is it necessary for Controllers to extend Illuminate\Routing\Controller? and Why?

Tags: php, laravel

- Is it necessary for controllers to extend `Illuminate\Routing\Controller`?
- What happens if a simple controller class that does not extend `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` is used?
- What are the benefits of extending `Illuminate\Routing\Controller`?

Example:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
}


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}


Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');
```

vs

```
class Controller
{
}


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}


Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');
```

Comment: What are your reasons/concerns for not wanting to use it?

Comment: Why do I need to? This is the question. The other question is about its benefits. I don't write/use code without a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below answers for your questions

1. It's not compulsory to extend base controller. It will work properly without extending base controller.
2. It will work as usual without creating any problem, will show your expected result.
3. It will include lots of benefit with your simple controller. It's always recommended to use base controller. It includes lot of things under the hood like middleware

   ```
   public function middleware($middleware, array $options = [])
   {
   foreach ((array) $middleware as $m) {
       $this->middleware[] = [
           'middleware' => $m,
           'options' => &$options,
       ];
   }

   return new ControllerMiddlewareOptions($options);
   }
   ```

Magic method

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [{$method}] does not exist on [".get_class($this).'].');
}
```

Just explore that class, you will get complete idea what you can do after extending it.

Comment: I needed to hear that in theory/design there is no need to extend BaseController for routing to work (By experiment it does work). Now, I will use it when I found the need for its functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to Laravel's official documentation, Controllers are not required to extend a base class. However, you will not have access to convenience features such as the `middleware`, `validate`, and `dispatch` methods.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#defining-controllers